# Linq query execution

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Hello I have a method that filter a list of string I want my code to consider the modification I made to the list after calling my method . here is my code:

```
public class Program
{
    public IEnumerable <String> Filter(List <string> strings)
        {

        var result = strings
                .Where(s => s.StartsWith("L"))
                .OrderBy(s=> s).ToList();


        return  result;

        }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var strings = new List<string>();
        var filtredStrings = new Program().Filter(strings);
        strings.Add("item1");
        strings.Add("Life");
        strings.Add("Lasagna");

        foreach( var s in filtredStrings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to apply the sorting _after_ you add the strings to your list

Comment: Also, why not just make `Filter()` static so you dont have to instantiate a `new Program()`?

Comment: @OnkelToob actually i want to acheive this without modifying the order of the call

Comment: @macccettura I'll consider that . thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't call `.ToList()` inside `Filter(...)`.
This way the enumerable will only execute when you iterate over it.

```
void Main()
{
    var strings = new List<string>();
    var filtredStrings = Filter(strings);
    strings.Add("item1");
    strings.Add("Life");
    strings.Add("Lasagna");

    foreach( var s in filtredStrings)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}

// Define other methods, classes and namespaces here
public static IEnumerable<String> Filter(List<string> strings)
{
    // Don't call .ToList()
    return strings.Where(s => s.StartsWith("L")).OrderBy(s => s);
}
```

Output:

```
Lasagna
Life
```